# Modifying the last element of an array in MongoDB

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have an object structure like this:

```
 {
    name: "...",
    pockets: [
        {
            cdate: "....",
            items: [...]
        }
        ...
    ]
 }
```

In an update operation, I want to add some records into the *items* field of the last *pocket* item. Using dot notation is the only way that I know to access a sub document, but I can't get what I want. So, I'm looking for something like these:

- pockets.-1.items
- pockets.$last.items

Is it possible to modify the last element? If yes, how?

Comment: Am I correct that you want to modify `items`, not fetch it?

Comment: Yes, you are correct. In fetching, I can use $slice operator.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this can't be done with a simple update unless you have some other way to match the last pocket.

Comment: Can you modify header to "..... in MongodB"? This is not clear.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of a way to do this using a single-line query.  But you could select the record, update and then save it.

```
var query = <insert query here>;
var mydocs = db.mycollection.find(query);
for (var i=0 ; i<mydocs.length ; i++) {
    mydocs[i].pockets[pockets.length-1].items.push('new item');
    db.mycollection.save(mydoc);
}
```

Comment: this may not be thread-safe as another process could have modified the array after the find and before the save.

Answer (score 3):

I don't believe it is possible to do it atomically.  There is a [request](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2476) for this functionality to be added to MongoDB.

If you can assure thread-safety in your **application** code, you could probably use a sequence of $pop from pockets array (that removes the last element from pockets) to variable p and then $addToSet to p.items, now you can $push p back into pockets.   But if your application doesn't have a way to assure only one process may be doing this at one time, then another process could modify the array in the middle of those steps and you may end up losing that update.

You might also look into "Update if current" semantics [here](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Atomic+Operations) to see another way you can work around possible race by multiple threads issue.