# Mongodb how to update last item in array

Tags: mongodb, updates

can somebody tell me please if is possible to update last item in array of documents? For example in this document:

```
{
   name: 'my name',
   someArray: [
       {rate: 10},
       {rate: 9},
       {rate: 20}
   ]
}
```

I would like to update last item with **rate:20 to rate: 50**.
How to update exactly the last item in Mongodb?
Thanks.

Comment: take pop (remove) and then push new item

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Modifying the last element of an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10708109/modifying-the-last-element-of-an-array)

Comment: Yes it is duplicate but original header does not contain Mongodb keyword. It is not clear. It could be anything.

Answer (score 1):

One option is using an update pipeline:

1. Split the array into the last item and all the rest.
2. update the last item
3. Build the array again using `$concatArrays`

```
db.collection.update(
  {name: "my name"},
  [
    {$set: {
      lastItem: {$last: "$someArray"},
      rest: {$slice: ["$someArray", 0, {$subtract: [{$size: "$someArray"}, 1]}]}
    }
    },
    {$set: {"lastItem.rate": 50}},
    {$set: {
      someArray: {$concatArrays: ["$rest", ["$lastItem"]]},
      lastItem: "$$REMOVE",
      rest: "$$REMOVE"
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example - concatArrays](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VRMymkVs5u5)

Another option is using `$reduce`:

Here we are iterating on the array, for each item checking if it is the last one, and if so updating it:

```
db.collection.update(
  {name: "my name"},
  [
  {$set: {lastIndex: {$subtract: [{$size: "$someArray"}, 1]}}},
  {$set: {
      lastIndex: "$$REMOVE",
      someArray: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$someArray",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {
            $concatArrays: [
              "$$value",
              [
                {
                  $cond: [
                    {$eq: [{$size: "$$value"}, "$lastIndex"]},
                    {$mergeObjects: [
                       "$$this",
                        {rate: 50}
                      ]
                    },
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example - reduce](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rqQJ2X5mGL4)